# should &A[1] be the same address as A itself?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

for the following code

```
//gcc 5.4.0

#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <assert.h>

struct a{
    int a;
};

void change(struct a * a) {
    a->a = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct a * a = malloc(4*sizeof(struct a));
    a[3].a = 2;
    assert(a[3].a == 2);
    change(&a[3]);
    assert(a[3].a == 5);
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

why doesnt `change(&a[3]);` pass the address of `change(&a);` or `change(a);` itself as isnt the address of a[3] just a itself?

eg

a = pointer

3 = index 3 of the pointer

a[3] = structure at index 3

&a[3] = address of the structure > address of a, as per struct a * a, a points to struct a, and as a[3] is a pointer from a to the 3rd structure, the parent of the third structure is a itself

Comment: `a == &a[0]`. `&a[3] == (a+3)`.

Comment: `&a[3]` is a pointer to the fourth element in the "array" `a`.

Comment: Egad. Too many different meanings of `a`.

Comment: so `&a[3]` is the address of the structure at index 3 of the array `a` ?

Comment: @aschepler aaaaaaaaaaa!

Answer (score 2):

You have many `a`'s in your code.

1. A Type of struct `a`
2. An element of this struct which is an integer `a`
3. A pointer to this struct `a` in main. Name of pointer is also `a`

This is really not a good way to go about it but here is the explanation of each line.

```
struct a * a = malloc(4*sizeof(struct a));  // Allocate memory to a (no 3) (pointer) of 4 structures . (i.e. 4 structures)
a[3].a = 2;                  //the third structure's element (a) has value 2.
assert(a[3].a == 2);         // Check
change(&a[3]);               // Pass the address of a[3] (third element of structure array to function
                            // Function will change the element a of a[3] to 5
assert(a[3].a == 5);        // verify that a[3].a == 5 
printf("Hello, world!\n");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use good programming practices as [@Rishikesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555525/rishikesh-raje) suggests, take a look to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices#Naming_conventions) in Wkipedia.

But, in any case, as [@aschelper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) says, `&a[3]` is the address of the fourth element of the array.

This is that way because of the [precedence of the operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The `[]` operator has more precedence that `&` operator, so C first gets the fourth (index 3) element of the array and then it returns it address.